# Motivo e entendimento de sinalização rejeitada

Tags: debate, sinalização

As sinalizações visam alertar os moderadores para os conteúdos dos quais não estão dentro do escopo do SOpt e ajudam a manter a ordem. Dessa forma os usuários podem fazer isso, contribuindo com a comunidade.

[Nesta questão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/147417/ubuntu-16-04-sem-som) sinalizei com o comentário:

> Relacionado a outra comunidade.

E vi que a sinalização foi rejeitada, apenas com o aviso:

> Relacionado a outra comunidade. – Marcelo de Andrade ontem   rejeitado - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention

O que houve de errado em minha sinalização? Caso eu realmente tenha utilizado de maneira incorreta, qual foi ela para que eu não repita?

Pois está claro que a pergunta está fora do escopo e pertence à outra [comunidade](https://askubuntu.com/).

Comment: Não pertence porque está em português, talvez por isso tenha sido rejeitada.

Comment: Porque não* está em português, é isso @JorgeB.?

Comment: Marcelo o problema é que ela está em português e por isso mesmo não pode pertencer à outra comunidade.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A pergunta está em português, então certamente ela não pertence ao AskUbuntu que é uma comunidade em inglês. Sendo em português, a maior chance é dela pertencer aqui no SOpt mesmo. Então o maior problema desta sinalização é pedindo para mudar para uma comunidade errada.

Se a intenção era que fizesse uma migração para o AskUbuntu, mesmo que fosse uma pergunta válida para lá, existe uma impossibilidade técnica que impede até mesmo moderadores.

De qualquer forma sinalizações específicas para moderação geralmente são para casos onde precisa da intervenção urgente ou casos onde a comunidade não pode lidar de forma natural. Claro que os casos que cabem sinalização deste tipo ou não, são cinzentos.

Neste caso um simples voto para fechar seria suficiente para deixar toda comunidade, com privilégio de análise, ciente do problema e permitir que todos possam tomar alguma atitude. Isso vale inclusive para os moderadores que podem analisar, o que foi feito. Note que não havia um voto de fechamento anterior, o que deveria.

A moderação costuma entrar em ação quando a comunidade não pode fazer, seja porque ela não tem esse poder, seja porque precisa urgência, ou tem algum "rolo" maior. Em geral não é necessário sinalizar qualquer coisa. Menos ainda sinalizar algo que a comunidade pode conduzir bem.

Estamos, entre os moderadores, debatendo o uso excessivo de sinalizações. Não entendam errado, é para sinalizar, mas não precisa sinalizar coisas tranquilas da comunidade resolver. Perguntas como essa ajudam todos entenderem melhor quando usar e quando evitar.

É claro que tem um jeito fácil de saber quando usou errado (quando ela foi rejeitada :) ). Só que faz é que pode errar. Mas é o tipo de "erro" bom.

Se não concorda, pode comentar ou abrir um debate. Estamos ouvindo, mas basicamente esse é o entendimento atual.

Comment: Acredito que entendi e fui procurar sobre os privilégios, o  "voto para fechar" é necessário 3000 pontos para votar para fechar ou abrir perguntas. Como ainda não há a interface(botão/link), entendi de forma incorreta a sinalização.

Comment: @MarcelodeAndrade acho que não percebeste o que o bigown quis dizer. É certo que a pergunta é offtopic, mas não pode ser migrada para lado nenhum, porque não é ontopic em lado nenhum.

Comment: @MarcelodeAndrade o motivo de sinalização para a moderação é mais para atentar para algo bem fora do normal, algo que precise de explicação, ou urgência. Um outro motivo talvez fosse mais adequado, ou só chamar atenção em comentário. Eu cheguei pensar em marcar como útil porque teve lá sua utilidade, mas aí poderia passar a mensagem errada que é o tipo de sinalização adequada sempre. Só entenda que não fez nada ruim, mesmo não sendo a melhor sinalização, serviu para alguma coisa boa. Então espero que não se sinta mal, só tem motivos para se sentir bem ;)

Comment: Terminei não comentando sobre isso, apesar de ter pensado sobre a migração da questão entre as comunidades, também imaginei que houvesse impossibilidades técnicas, o problema mesmo foi o entendimento incorreto e o esquecimento do sistema de votos devido a falta de privilégio para ele. Pode ficar tranquilo, @bigown, só se aprende com erros :D

Comment: Eu tenho trocentas sinalizações rejeitadas :D

Answer (score 3):

Não sei dizer se esse foi o motivo, somente o moderador que recusou poderá explicar. Todavia, existem alguns pontos que podem ter levado a essa rejeição.

Em uma tradução direta, pelo Google (meu inglês é péssimo) a mensagem que você recebeu é:

> Flag só deve ser usado para fazer moderadores conscientes do conteúdo que requer a sua intervenção

Em resumo, sinalize somente aquilo que nós não podemos resolver sem eles.

Existe um motivo de fechamento de perguntas como **fora de escopo** ou **esta pergunta pertence a outro site da rede Stack Exchange**. Se você observar, verá que o @bigown fechou a pergunta como **fora de escopo**, o que existem opção para votar.

Por esse motivo, acho que aconteceu essa "rejeição" da flag.

Afirmo novamente que eu não posso afirmar que esse foi o motivo.

Comment: Basicamente é isso, na minha resposta eu até detalho um pouco mais. Eu já traduzi as mensagens e estão aguardando revisar e mandar para o sistema.

Comment: É, comentei agora na resposta do bigown. Deixei passar despercebido o sistema de votos.

Comment: @MarcelodeAndrade Eu também esqueci da questão do privilégio.