# Sinalização "Não é uma resposta" rejeitada por moderador - qual o motivo?

Tags: debate, sinalização

*Não sei se eu deveria colocar isso no Meta, se houver uma maneira mais apropriada, por favor avisem.*

Ultimamente algumas sinalizações minhas de "Não é uma resposta" tiveram a seguinte rejeição:

> rejeitado - um moderador revisou sua sinalização, mas não achou evidência que a confirme

Bom, eu tento entender para não repetir o erro, mas alguns casos me parecem "estranhos" e não consegui entender exatamente se eu avaliei errado ou se foi o moderador (por mais provável que tenha sido "eu", é importante entender para não cometer o mesmo erro).

### Casos

**1.  O que significa o erro “Execução de scripts foi desabilitada neste sistema”?** [Resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/453573/100416):

> Eu que não sei oque é cmdlet fico boiando :/

Isso não me parece ser uma resposta, nem uma nova pergunta (talvez pudesse ser, se melhor formulada). Talvez fosse adequado como comentário da resposta marcada como solução, que citou o `cmdlet`.

**2. Como selecionar ultimo registro da tabela MySQL com last ou outro comando?** [Resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/452884/100416):

> ```
> SELECT MAX(id) as maxId FROM table
> ```
>
> Acho que este tipo de consulta traz o maior valor e não o último!

Só que isso me parece mais um comentário sobre a outra [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/436452/100416) que colocou exatamente o mesmo código, não uma resposta nova.

**3. Como criar um efeito da imagem levantar ao passar o mouse por cima?** [Resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13511/como-criar-um-efeito-da-imagem-levantar-ao-passar-o-mouse-por-cima/452702#452702) deletada, mas minha sinalização havia sido recusada. O usuário havia compartilhado um código diminuindo o `height` e `width` no `hover` (se bem me lembro), o que não responde à pergunta, apenas diminui a imagem.

### Perguntas

1. Minhas sinalizações foram realmente inválidas? Inclusive no terceiro caso, que ficou com 4 votos negativos e foi removida? (não sei se foi removida pelo próprio usuário)
2. Se eu discordar, como nos casos citados, o que eu posso fazer? Sinalizar novamente, aceitar que existe algo ali que interpretei errado e deixar de lado, sinalizar por outro motivo?

Comment: Eu não faço parte da moderação e nunca fiz parte então não posso dizer como que são recepcionados os eventos de sinalização, minha visão é a mesma que a sua. Ao clicar em sinalizar no último item `precisa de atenção dos moderadores` permite que seja anexada uma mensagem junto da sinalização permitindo o ser mais específico quanto a sinalização assim explicando o que passou despercebido na sinalização anterior. Agora não sei lhe informar se no caso de rejeições consecutivas de sinalização implica em penalidade ou sanção .

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Foi um erro mesmo, tinha uma outra muito ruim junto e a UI que demonstra o conteúdo sinalizado é um pouco confusa e eu achei que a sinalização era na outra resposta, que é muito ruim, mas ainda é uma resposta, então eu aceitei só a sinalização de baixa qualidade que tinha também. mas foi engano, lamento.
2. Parece uma resposta. Ele não tem certeza, é simples, não diz nada mais que dar o código, mas ainda é uma resposta, inclusive igual a outras que não foram sinalizadas. Talvez de baixa qualidade #Ficaadica para todos :)
3. Mesmo caso, é um resposta horrível, ele funcionaria pior ainda como comentário, mas ainda é um resposta. Resposta errada é uma resposta.

Sim, ela não deveria ter sido removida porque é uma resposta. Os negativos indicam justamente que ela é de baixa qualidade. Na verdade não entendo porque as pessoas negativam não respostas. Por exemplo spam ou algo que não seja uma pergunta ou resposta, para que negativar, sinalize e ele será apagado.

O negativo serve para algo que ficará no site. Se as pessoas usassem mais o negativo em conteúdos ruins que ficarão no site em vez de gastar nessas coisas teríamos uma classificação melhor. Muita coisa ruim fica sem negativo.

Se discordar pode reclamar no meta, mas dá muito trabalho para pouca coisa. Acho que não consegue sinalizar novamente, pelo menos motivo, quase sempre que o "não é uma resposta" foi recusada o "baixa qualidade" será. Se achar que foi um erro claro como o item 1 e quiser pode sinalizar novamente com motivo personalizado dando um curto argumento ou indicando que considera um erro crasso. Para os outros itens seria rejeitado de novo, só a baixa qualidade caberia.

O meta seria o caso quando precisa discutir o assunto (esta pergunta aqui até é normal porque é mais um suporte). Porém já discutimos isso várias vezes (veja abaixo os *links*), e raramente valerá a pena discutir de novo postagens individuais. Uma discussão valeria para mudar toda interpretação do que não é resposta, mas duvido que se chegaria a uma mudança.

Eu não lembro se no meta ou no chat eu concordei com o Gabe quando só ele era moderador e CM que as pessoas abusavam de sinalização de não é resposta. Eu postei algo a respeito, mas não acho, vou deixar alguns *links* que ajudam entender:

- [Uma resposta curta deve ser apagada?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7052/101)
- ["Resposta" que levam a resposta, mas não é a resposta, o que fazer?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6645/101)
- [Respostas apenas com código - O que fazer?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7172/101)
- [Respostas na linguagem errada devem ser excluídas?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2465/101)
- [Respostas "Consegui Resolver"](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8138/101)
- [O que fazer com respostas curtas?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/574/101)
- [Porque esta sinalização foi rejeitada?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6329/101) (quase duplicata)
- [Motivo e entendimento de sinalização rejeitada](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5271/101)
- [O que se passou aqui?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6395/101)

Eu até acho que algumas respostas ficariam melhor como comentário, mas a filosofia é tentar respeitar a tentativa de responder tanto quanto possível, o que é quase certo que implicará em negativos nela. Eu não me importaria de sair apagando quase tudo que não é ótimo, mas seria bem trabalhoso e acho que a SE não ficaria feliz. De uma forma ou de outra pode ajudar no SEO.

Eu vivo falando que se tivesse mais negativo em conteúdo de baixa qualidade poderíamos fechar menos perguntas. [As pessoas gostam de reclamar](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8295/101) mas fazer algo para classificar de forma clara que algo é ruim elas não querem, então fechar e remover acaba tendo que ser a solução, mas não deveria, por isso tentamos ao máximo manter conteúdo, com a esperança até que depois de fechado algo seja melhorado e possa reabrir, mas que não seja colocando mais conteúdo ruim. Pergunta ruim tende atrair resposta ruim. Se perguntas ruins, que só servem ao AP fossem sempre negativadas ou pelo menos não recebessem positivo mais ficaria aberto porque um dia o sistema removeria automaticamente. Mas se tiver um positivo na pergunta ou na resposta ela ficará para sempre no site, então precisa ser mais restrito, precisa fechar para indicar claramente que não é um conteúdo bom. As pessoas que positivam ou deixam de negativar postagens ruins são responsáveis por ter que fechar mais que o normal.

Queria fazer uma campanha para negativar e sinalizar como baixa qualidade mais conteúdo, com isso teremos que fechar e remover menos. [Eu já propus até aceitar mais coisas, manter o conteúdo e colocar avisos que o conteúdo é ruim](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7903/101) ([outra](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7016/101)).

Sinalizações abusivas podem trazer advertência ou suspensão, mas diferença de interpretação não pode ser considerado abuso. Não lembro que algum usuário que sinalizou abusivamente, teria que ser algo proposital, ou uma quantidade grande de coisas aleatórias. Nós entendemos a boa intenção da pessoa mesmo quando não concordamos.

Espero que isso coloque luz para todos terem suas sinalizações mais aceitas (a esmagadora maioria é).

Comment: Certo, entendi o que ocorreu. Não costumo sinalizar algo como "baixa qualidade" por conta do texto intimidador de "É improvável que esta resposta seja recuperável por meio de edição e talvez seja necessário removê-la.", muitas vezes eu acredito que uma edição do próprio autor poderia melhorar. De qualquer modo, darei uma olhada nos links que você compartilhou, obrigado pela atenção :)

Comment: @RafaelTavares de fato, mas hoje em dia é raro alguém melhorar. E convenhamos que será mais fácil (não é muito) ela reverter a situação assim do que se a resposta for removida, até porque ela não pode restaurar uma postagem removida pelo sistema. Estritamente a sinalização de baixa qualidade não é muito certa, mas o site todo não está muito certo.