# Minha sinalização pra fechar a pergunta como fora de escopo foi rejeitada, e a pergunta foi fechada como fora de escopo

Tags: suporte

Fiz uma sinalização nessa pergunta [Desenvolvendo no sublime](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/500519/desenvolvendo-no-sublime) para fechar como fora de escopo, minha sinalização foi rejeitada e a pergunta foi fechada como fora de escopo. Não é a primeira vez que isso acontece, minhas dúvidas são:

- A pergunta já havia sido fechada como fora de escopo quando
  rejeitaram minha sinalização?
- Eu posso acabar sendo punido pelo sistema se minhas sinalizações
  forem rejeitadas?

Não que isso me irrite e machuque meu ego, é mais pra entender o sistema.

Comment: Sobre o segundo tópico, sim, mas não sei quais as possíveis punições. Quando eu tinha menos de 1500 reput. , já tive que ficar 1 semana sem poder sinalizar porque tive muitas sinalizções rejeitadas em pouco tempo. Tanto que passei a prestar mais atenção nas minhas análises de P/R depois disso :)

Comment: Não, não pode ser punido por isso, a não ser que estivesse avacalhando com o sistema de sinalização. A rejeição pode ter sido acidental, desse caso especifico, não sei afirmar agora (algumas coisas são complicadas de analisar, lhe confirmo depois). De qualquer forma eu mesmo já tive sinalizações rejeitadas ou disputadas.... Sobre outras situações que ocorreram contigo, podem ser realmente que usou a flag de forma errada, não tem como falar de todos casos.

Comment: PS: pelo que vi você tem 2 flags apenas rejeitas, a outra rejeitada é de 2017, que não deve ser o caso. Então ocorreu apenas 2 vezes, talvez o moderador ou pessoas na fila de analise, acharam naquele momento que a postagem era valida, pode ter sido apenas uma confusão e sua flag estava certa, mas é um pouco "interpretativo". Aparentemente estão "corretas". De qualquer forma como visualizamos muitas flags por dia, as vezes pode ter acontecido algum engano mesmo.

Comment: Em [post](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8336/137387) similar ao seu o moderador havia dito que a interface de analise das sinalizações não é exemplo primoroso de UX e é propensa a erros.

Comment: O motivo da rejeição foi "Usar sinalizações padrões ajuda-nos priorizar problemas e resolvê-las mais rápido. Por favor familiarize-se com a lista de sinalizações padrões". Pedir para fechar com um comentário não é adequado, sinalize para fechar que entra na fila. Sinalizações com comentário são para casos graves ou inusitados que requer uma explicação especificação, oque não é o caso de pedir para fechar.

Comment: Valeu Maniero, eu procurei lá se tinha a opção fora de escopo, não lembro se antigamente era mais fácil, mas agora encontrei lá :)

Comment: Só pra reforçar, quando sinaliza com comentário, só moderador pode tratar. Se sinaliza com alguma padrão, a comunidade participa. Sinalização com comentário é bem exceção mesmo. Um exemplo válido de sinalização específica para moderador é quando o usuário revela credenciais indevidamente, a conta tem algum comportamento suspeito, ou qualquer outro que requeira tratamento "especializado".

Comment: Apenas fazendo um gancho. O que aconteceu com o OP também já aconteceu comigo. Na verdade praticamente todas as perguntas em que minhas sinalizações são rejeitadas acabam eventualmente sendo fechadas / removidas. Um erro meu (com o devido mea culpa) : As vezes reporto questões com "precisa de atenção dos moderadores" para esclarecer motivos específicos de algo que até cabe em uma categoria mais específica.

Comment: Uma dica pessoal: Trate a sinalização como algo que vai cair na fila dos moderadores de forma parecida com que os votos para fechar caem na fila de análise comum. Pense em todas as ações que você já tomou meio que no piloto automático após trocentas análises... Por mais experientes que os mods sejam, e por mais boa vontade que eles tenham, todo mundo é humano e eventualmente escorrega na jaca. Ter algumas poucas sinalizações recusadas, ainda mais com algumas "falsas recusas", não é demérito para o usuário. Isso faz parte do funcionamento do site.